# What’s a person who borrows something but won’t return it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, idiom-requests

I cannot find the right words or expression or idiom to describe a person who borrows something from someone but will not return it to its owner.

Also, I would like to know the word that describes a person who no matter how many times you tell them to give you back the money, they just smile and do nothing.

Comment: Verb *to welsh* and associated agent noun *welsher* are now rejected by editors as ethnic slurs. I'm not sure the gap they left in the lexicon has been filled.

Comment: I see. Yet, can the word  welser be used with a friend who won't give me back the money he borrows?

Comment: Also, can u tell the word that can be used to describe a person in 2? Is there an expression as 'having a thick skin.'

Comment: Well I don't have a word for the person but the *act* could be called **tingo** - to take all the objects one desires from the house of a friend, one at a time, by asking to borrow them

Comment: A *delinquent*?

Comment: @jxh this doesn't work in British English where "delinquent", usually preceded by "juvenile" has nothing to do with borrowing but instead with antisocial behaviour and petty crime.

Comment: @briandonovan "welch" despite being basically an alternative spelling is rather more acceptable [(Cambridge)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/welch). Or perhaps I should say "less unacceptable", it's not a term I'd choose.

Comment: I think you can cross _borrower_ off the list, anyway.

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, it is a pun. *Delinquent* means both "a trouble maker" and "late with payment".

Comment: @jxh your latter sense is US-specific.

Comment: @ChrisH: ngrams shows *delinquent payment* is starting to pick up in British English as well.

Comment: Dagwood's neighbor Herb.

Comment: I think "leech" in an Answer below is the best for the borrower.  And,  there is an obvious word for someone who lends more than twice after not being paid back.

Comment: Homer J. Simpson

Answer (score 4):

The word "**deadbeat**" is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deadbeat) as "one who persistently fails to pay personal debts or expenses", though other dictionaries specify that this usage is particular to North America.

As for someone who "smiles and does nothing" when someone demands payment of these debts, I suppose one might call that a *shameless* deadbeat.

Comment: 'The Shameless Deadbeats' sounds like a rock group. Is it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Evidently not.  A quick internet search for the exact (case-insensitive) phrase "the Shameless Deadbeats" returns only two results,  a message board post complaining about the Chicago police, and a _Duck Tales_ fanfic.

Comment: How do I make sure nobody pinches my intellectual property?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, one could make the case that it's actually _my_ intellectual property. : ) But it appears that the domain name "shamlessdeadbeats.com" is still available for registration, if you've got fifteen dollars lying around.

Comment: Don't rock the boat. _Fifteen dollars_? Can you lend it me?

Comment: I see what you did there. : )

Comment: For me, *deadbeat* doesn't line up perfectly with the description in the OP.  For me, the epitome of a deadbeat is someone who can't hold down a job.  *Deadbeat dads* are men who don't pay child support.

Answer (score 4):

I think of the word leech.  It refers to FPT sites. Several years ago these sites would often have ratios where people would get a certain amount of downloadable bytes for every byte they uploaded. Sites that did not have ratios were said to be "leech" sites because you could download all you wanted without having to upload.

The term now more refers to any individual who is often into the piracy scene and doesn't do anything but download files for cracked versions of software, movies, music and so on.

They don't  share what they have downloaded and don't provide help to others looking for certain files. I guess that might help you

Comment: +1 for leech.  The answer would have been better if it had started with leech as blood-sucker and gone on to its long usage to refer to someone of the type in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ideas (although I like 'Dagwood's neighbor Herb' very much).

**Scofflaw** -- someone who shamelessly ignores his financial and other legal obligations; this only intersects partially with what you're looking for, I think.

**Scrounger** -- a person who borrows from or lives off others.

**Moocher** or **mooch** -- from *to mooch*, to borrow a small item or amount without intending to return or repay it.

**Schnorrer** (Yiddish) -- I'm not sure if this matches up well.  The definitions I've found on the internet don't seem to, however, the same word in German works great.

(If things get really bad, you could say *parasite* -- but that is very strong.)

Answer (score 0):

### Blagger

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blag):

> **blag**
>
> British  informal
>
> verb (blags, blagging, blagged)
>   [with object]
>
> 1) Manage to obtain (something) by using persuasion or guile:
>    ‘they blagged two free tickets to France’